# how do I commit and push to github from python shell?

Tags: python, github, python-idle

I have three .py files saved in the python shell/IDLE. I would like to commit and push them to my GitHub account/repo. Is this possible? and if so how?

Comment: No. You have to do this from a command line/GUI git client.

Comment: @MorganThrapp not true, you could use a library like [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython)

Comment: It's worth mentioning, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) states, that using `shell=True` in `subprocess.call()` is not completely safe, as it can lead to [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection).

Answer (score 5):

To do it from macOS (Mac terminal) using the shell from python, you can do this:

```
#Import dependencies
from subprocess import call

#Commit Message
commit_message = "Adding sample files"

#Stage the file 
call('git add .', shell = True)

# Add your commit
call('git commit -m "'+ commit_message +'"', shell = True)

#Push the new or update files
call('git push origin master', shell = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a python library for git in python called [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html).
Another way to this is doing it from shell(if you're using linux).
For Example:

```
from subprocess import call
call('git add .', shell = True)
call('git commit -a "commiting..."', shell = True)
call('git push origin master', shell = True)
```

Comment: how to we set the path?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, which path?

Answer (score 3):

You can execute arbitrary shell commands using the `subprocess` module.

**Setting up a test folder to play with:**

```
$ cd ~/test
$ touch README.md
$ ipython
```

**Working with git from IPython:**

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: print subprocess.check_output('git init', shell=True)

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/parelio/test/.git/

In [3]: print subprocess.check_output('git add .', shell=True)

In [4]: print subprocess.check_output('git commit -m "a commit"', shell=True)

[master (root-commit) 16b6499] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README.md
```

**A note on `shell=True`:**

Don't use `shell=True` when you are working with untrusted user input. See the [warning in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

**One more note:**

As with many things in programming - just because you can doesn't mean that you should. My personal preference in a situation like this would be to use an existing library rather than roll my own.